Calling the org itself with a named credential still results in a 401 HTTP response with INVALID_SESSION_ID error, but why?
I'm trying to obtain a valid session id to save time and resources on a feature I'm working on. I have a middleware that is supposed to receive requests from Salesforce and then perform calls back to Salesforce's REST API to retrieve some data.
The payload passes along the session id from Salesforce and the URL the service is supposed to hit to get the data it needs. The problem is that depending on the context that the call is made, the session id is not valid for performing requests on the API.
So what I'm trying to do is to call Salesforce through the REST API using a named credential, so that I can obtain a valid session ID from there using UserInfo.getSessionId from an invocable action that is hit with the named credential. In theory, because Salesforce is supposed to use the named credential, it is an API request, so Salesforce would hit /services/data/vXX.0/actions/custom/apex/theAction as it would be hitting any other external service. The problem is that this is not what happens. When Salesforce tries to hit the services endpoint, the transaction fails because of this "invalid session ID" error, saying that the current context is not able to make API callouts. But this makes little sense to me, since Salesforce should be using the named credential instead of the current context (so it wouldn't matter if the code is being called from a LWC or a Flow).
Is there a way I can obtain a valid, REST API-enabled Session ID to pass along to the service?
Considerations:

Yes, I have full control of the service, so safety is not an issue in this case.
No, OAuth 2.0 is not an option without refactoring a lot of things and adding storage to the app (which increases hosting cost).


This depends on how named credential is set up and what type of flow you're using. Some flows run in the caller context, sounds like your implementation. The flows that do not run in caller context or could run in context different from caller are few - Client Cred is one of them.

After posting this question I turned my view to the "Default Scopes" setting in the Salesforce Auth. Provider used by the credential, and the scopes in the connected app itself.
I added the same scopes for the two (as shown below), and re-authenticated the named credential. Then the calls started working just fine!
api full refresh_token offline_access

